# Perfect JSON format from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, reactjs

**The source data:**

```
Dialogflow Response : id: \"9f912860-e5c6-4e57-934b-8639595b947f-d571b79b\"\nlang: \"en\"\nsession_id: \"3e22f813-79bb-b29a-1def-4c5e4ce4b23b\"\ntimestamp: \"2020-11-02T12:38:09.875Z\"\nresult {\n  source: \"agent\"\n  resolved_query: \"hi\"\n  action: \"input.welcome\"\n  score: 1.0\n  parameters {\n  }\n  contexts {\n    name: \"awaits_choice\"\n    lifespan: 5\n    parameters {\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo\"\n        value {\n          number_value: 2.1012875E7\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo.original\"\n        value {\n          string_value: \"21012875\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  contexts {\n    name: \"accountno\"\n    lifespan: 49\n    parameters {\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo\"\n        value {\n          number_value: 2.1012875E7\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo.original\"\n        value {\n          string_value: \"21012875\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  metadata {\n    intent_id: \"5bb77027-405a-401e-ac3f-497c471359c8\"\n    intent_name: \"Default Welcome Intent\"\n    webhook_used: \"false\"\n    webhook_for_slot_filling_used: \"false\"\n    is_fallback_intent: \"false\"\n  }\n  fulfillment {\n    speech: \"Hi, I’m Phoenix from Central Huson. Thanks for reaching out to me. I can answer all your questions and provide the right information you are seeking.\"\n    messages {\n      platform: \"google\"\n      display_text: \"Hi, I’m Phoenix from Central Huson. Thanks for reaching out to me. I can answer all your questions and provide the right information you are seeking.\"\n      text_to_speech: \"Hi, I’m Patrick from The MDC. For all emergencies, Please call 9-1-1 immediately! Or call us on 860-278-7850. You can ask me any question. Are you an existing customer?\"\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        string_value: \"simple_response\"\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      platform: \"telephony\"\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 14.0\n      }\n      text: \"Hi, I’m Patrick from The MDC. For all emergencies, Please call 9-1-1 immediately! Or call us on 860-278-7850. So, are you existing customer?\"\n    }\n    messages {\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 0.0\n      }\n      speech {\n        string_value: \"Hi, I’m Phoenix from Central Huson. Thanks for reaching out to me. I can answer all your questions and provide the right information you are seeking.\"\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      payload {\n        fields {\n          key: \"richContent\"\n          value {\n            list_value {\n              values {\n                list_value {\n                  values {\n                    struct_value {\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"image\"\n                        value {\n                          struct_value {\n                            fields {\n                              key: \"src\"\n                              value {\n                                struct_value {\n                                  fields {\n                                    key: \"rawUrl\"\n                                    value {\n                                      string_value: \"https://example.com/images/logo.png\"\n                                    }\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                          }\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"subtitle\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"Please call us on 18009428274 or 911\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"text\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"<b> Stop </b> what you are doing <br> <b> Go </b> outside immediately <br> <b> Let us know </b> After making your report, a representative will come to your location and check for potential leaks or faulty appliances.\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"title\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"Emergency\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"type\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"accordion\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                    }\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 4.0\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 0.0\n      }\n      speech {\n        string_value: \"How can I help you today?\"\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      payload {\n        fields {\n          key: \"richContent\"\n          value {\n            list_value {\n              values {\n                list_value {\n                  values {\n                    struct_value {\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"options\"\n                        value {\n                          list_value {\n                            values {\n                              struct_value {\n                                fields {\n                                  key: \"text\"\n                                  value {\n                                    string_value: \"I am existing customer needs support\"\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                            values {\n                              struct_value {\n                                fields {\n                                  key: \"text\"\n                                  value {\n                                    string_value: \"Just browsing\"\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                            values {\n                              struct_value {\n                                fields {\n                                  key: \"text\"\n                                  value {\n                                    string_value: \"Ask me anything \"\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                          }\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"type\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"chips\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                    }\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 4.0\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\nstatus {\n  code: 200\n  error_type: \"success\"\n}\n
```

**expected output:**

```
{
  "id": "6ae5f723-538f-4df8-ad9a-88943b28484d-ee7586fb",
  "lang": "en",
  "session_id": "dfMessenger-12848231",
  "timestamp": "2020-11-06T06:46:50.794Z",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolved_query": "WELCOME",
    "action": "input.welcome",
    "score": 1,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": {
      "name": "awaits_choice",
      "lifespan": 5,
      "parameters": {}
    },
    "metadata": {
      "intent_id": "5bb77027-405a-401e-ac3f-497c471359c8",
      "intent_name": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "webhook_used": "false",
      "webhook_for_slot_filling_used": "false",
      "is_fallback_intent": "false"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Hi, I’m sathish",
      "messages": {
        "payload": {
          "fields": {
            "key": "richContent",
            "value": {
              "list_value": {
                "values": {
                  "list_value": {
                    "values": {
                      "struct_value": {
                        "fields": {
                          "key": "type",
                          "value": {
                            "string_value": "chips"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "lang": "en",
        "type": {
          "number_value": 4
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "error_type": "success"
  }
}
```

The above is my string I want to form a valid json string using node.js.
Can somebody help me to form the json string.
Thanks in advance.
I tried with regex replacing but not worked for me.
I have been wasted two days on this to form a perfect json for displaying the values.
I badly need someone to help me on this to get solve.

**Source code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

let rawdata = `Dialogflow Response : id: \"9f912860-e5c6-4e57-934b-8639595b947f-d571b79b\"\nlang: \"en\"\nsession_id: \"3e22f813-79bb-b29a-1def-4c5e4ce4b23b\"\ntimestamp: \"2020-11-02T12:38:09.875Z\"\nresult {\n  source: \"agent\"\n  resolved_query: \"hi\"\n  action: \"input.welcome\"\n  score: 1.0\n  parameters {\n  }\n  contexts {\n    name: \"awaits_choice\"\n    lifespan: 5\n    parameters {\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo\"\n        value {\n          number_value: 2.1012875E7\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo.original\"\n        value {\n          string_value: \"21012875\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  contexts {\n    name: \"accountno\"\n    lifespan: 49\n    parameters {\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo\"\n        value {\n          number_value: 2.1012875E7\n        }\n      }\n      fields {\n        key: \"accountNo.original\"\n        value {\n          string_value: \"21012875\"\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  metadata {\n    intent_id: \"5bb77027-405a-401e-ac3f-497c471359c8\"\n    intent_name: \"Default Welcome Intent\"\n    webhook_used: \"false\"\n    webhook_for_slot_filling_used: \"false\"\n    is_fallback_intent: \"false\"\n  }\n  fulfillment {\n    speech: \"Hi, I’m Phoenix from Central Huson. Thanks for reaching out to me. I can answer all your questions and provide the right information you are seeking.\"\n    messages {\n      platform: \"google\"\n      display_text: \"Hi, I’m Phoenix from Central Huson. Thanks for reaching out to me. I can answer all your questions and provide the right information you are seeking.\"\n      text_to_speech: \"Hi, I’m Patrick from The MDC. For all emergencies, Please call 9-1-1 immediately! Or call us on 860-278-7850. You can ask me any question. Are you an existing customer?\"\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        string_value: \"simple_response\"\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      platform: \"telephony\"\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 14.0\n      }\n      text: \"Hi, I’m Patrick from The MDC. For all emergencies, Please call 9-1-1 immediately! Or call us on 860-278-7850. So, are you existing customer?\"\n    }\n    messages {\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 0.0\n      }\n      speech {\n        string_value: \"Hi, I’m Phoenix from Central Huson. Thanks for reaching out to me. I can answer all your questions and provide the right information you are seeking.\"\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      payload {\n        fields {\n          key: \"richContent\"\n          value {\n            list_value {\n              values {\n                list_value {\n                  values {\n                    struct_value {\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"image\"\n                        value {\n                          struct_value {\n                            fields {\n                              key: \"src\"\n                              value {\n                                struct_value {\n                                  fields {\n                                    key: \"rawUrl\"\n                                    value {\n                                      string_value: \"https://example.com/images/logo.png\"\n                                    }\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                          }\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"subtitle\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"Please call us on 18009428274 or 911\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"text\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"<b> Stop </b> what you are doing <br> <b> Go </b> outside immediately <br> <b> Let us know </b> After making your report, a representative will come to your location and check for potential leaks or faulty appliances.\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"title\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"Emergency\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"type\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"accordion\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                    }\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 4.0\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 0.0\n      }\n      speech {\n        string_value: \"How can I help you today?\"\n      }\n    }\n    messages {\n      payload {\n        fields {\n          key: \"richContent\"\n          value {\n            list_value {\n              values {\n                list_value {\n                  values {\n                    struct_value {\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"options\"\n                        value {\n                          list_value {\n                            values {\n                              struct_value {\n                                fields {\n                                  key: \"text\"\n                                  value {\n                                    string_value: \"I am existing customer needs support\"\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                            values {\n                              struct_value {\n                                fields {\n                                  key: \"text\"\n                                  value {\n                                    string_value: \"Just browsing\"\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                            values {\n                              struct_value {\n                                fields {\n                                  key: \"text\"\n                                  value {\n                                    string_value: \"Ask me anything \"\n                                  }\n                                }\n                              }\n                            }\n                          }\n                        }\n                      }\n                      fields {\n                        key: \"type\"\n                        value {\n                          string_value: \"chips\"\n                        }\n                      }\n                    }\n                  }\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      lang: \"en\"\n      type {\n        number_value: 4.0\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\nstatus {\n  code: 200\n  error_type: \"success\"\n}\n`;
rawdata = rawdata.replace("Dialogflow Response : ", "");
rawdata = rawdata.replace(/\\n/g, "")
    .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
    .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
    .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
    .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
    .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
    .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
    .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");

console.log(rawdata);

const json = rawdata
    // add { at the beginning
    .replace(/^/, '{')
    // add } at the end
    .replace(/$/, '}')
    // add missing columns
    .replace(/(?<=\w+)(?=\s*\{)/g, ':')
    // add missing quotes to keys
    .replace(/(?<=\n\s*)(\w+)(?=\s*:)/g, '"$1"')
    // add missing commas
    .replace(/(?<![\{\[])(?=\s*\n+\s*)(?!\s*\n+\s*[\}\]])/g, ',');

// parse json to object
const data = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(data);

let dataStr = JSON.stringify(data);
fs.writeFileSync('response.json', dataStr);
```

Comment: What does "form a perfect JSON format" mean to you? Tried `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: yes tried but not working.` {
   "session":"dfMessenger-12848231",
   "query_input":"{  \"text\": {    \"textInputs\": [{      \"text\": \"Just browsing\"    }]  }}",
   "timezone":"America/Barbados"
}` need like this.

Comment: Can you include the source data you are working with and a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt to format a JSON string?

Comment: I have updated the question with exact source data.And I have added the source code of mine. Please review and help me out

Comment: If this data is part of some API response then you may also try processing it as a JSON response, something like [response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). Are you receiving this data as part of some server-side handling?

Comment: no its from bigquery logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using regex to try to fix it, not sure if it's working for all the situations, but it works for this one:

```js
const raw = `
id: "6ae5f723-538f-4df8-ad9a-88943b28484d-ee7586fb"
lang: "en"
session_id: "dfMessenger-12848231"
timestamp: "2020-11-06T06:46:50.794Z"
result {
  source: "agent"
  resolved_query: "WELCOME"
  action: "input.welcome"
  score: 1.0
  parameters {
  }
  contexts {
    name: "awaits_choice"
    lifespan: 5
    parameters {
    }
  }
  metadata {
    intent_id: "5bb77027-405a-401e-ac3f-497c471359c8"
    intent_name: "Default Welcome Intent"
    webhook_used: "false"
    webhook_for_slot_filling_used: "false"
    is_fallback_intent: "false"
  }
  fulfillment {
    speech: "Hi, I’m sathish"
    messages {
      platform: "google"
      display_text: "Hi,I'm Sathvish How can I help you?"
      lang: "en"
      type {
        string_value: "simple_response"
      }
    }
    messages {
      platform: "telephony"
      lang: "en"
      type {
        number_value: 14.0
      }
      text: "Hi, I’m Vishnu from The MDC. For all emergencies, Please call 9-1-1 immediately! Or call us on 123456789. So, are you existing customer?"
    }
    messages {
      lang: "en"
      type {
        number_value: 0.0
      }
      speech {
        string_value: "Hi, I'm sathvish How can I help you"
      }
    }
    messages {
      payload {
        fields {
          key: "richContent"
          value {
            list_value {
              values {
                list_value {
                  values {
                    struct_value {
                      fields {
                        key: "image"
                        value {
                          struct_value {
                            fields {
                              key: "src"
                              value {
                                struct_value {
                                  fields {
                                    key: "rawUrl"
                                    value {
                                      string_value: "https://google.com/images/logo.png"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                      fields {
                        key: "subtitle"
                        value {
                          string_value: "Please call us 123456"
                        }
                      }
                      fields {
                        key: "text"
                        value {
                          string_value: "<b> Stop </b> what you are doing <br> <b> Go </b> outside immediately."
                        }
                      }
                      fields {
                        key: "title"
                        value {
                          string_value: "Emergency"
                        }
                      }
                      fields {
                        key: "type"
                        value {
                          string_value: "accordion"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      lang: "en"
      type {
        number_value: 4.0
      }
    }
    messages {
      lang: "en"
      type {
        number_value: 0.0
      }
      speech {
        string_value: "How can I help you today?"
      }
    }
    messages {
      payload {
        fields {
          key: "richContent"
          value {
            list_value {
              values {
                list_value {
                  values {
                    struct_value {
                      fields {
                        key: "options"
                        value {
                          list_value {
                            values {
                              struct_value {
                                fields {
                                  key: "text"
                                  value {
                                    string_value: "I am existing customer needs support"
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            values {
                              struct_value {
                                fields {
                                  key: "text"
                                  value {
                                    string_value: "Just browsing"
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            values {
                              struct_value {
                                fields {
                                  key: "text"
                                  value {
                                    string_value: "Ask me anything "
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                      fields {
                        key: "type"
                        value {
                          string_value: "chips"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      lang: "en"
      type {
        number_value: 4.0
      }
    }
  }
}
status {
  code: 200
  error_type: "success"
}
`;

const json = raw
  // add { at the beginning
  .replace(/^/, '{')
  // add } at the end
  .replace(/$/, '}')
  // add missing columns
  .replace(/(?<=\w+)(?=\s*\{)/g, ':')
  // add missing quotes to keys
  .replace(/(?<=\n\s*)(\w+)(?=\s*:)/g, '"$1"')
  // add missing commas
  .replace(/(?<![\{\[])(?=\s*\n+\s*)(?!\s*\n+\s*[\}\]])/g, ',');
  
// parse json to object
const data = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(data);
```